# What's the right way of setting a valid timezone when using plone.app.event?

Tags: timezone, plone

After installing [plone.app.event v1.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.event/1.1) I see a bunch of warning messages on the log:

```
2014-04-28 16:06:11 WARNING plone.event The timezone BRT is not a valid timezone from the Olson database or pytz. Falling back to UTC.
```

I see there's a new control panel configlet, but I am wondering if there's another way of setting this outside of Plone. Environment variable? Buildout?

In the end, this **BRT** timezone information should be coming from the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the problem is just lack of documentation on the package.

The only thing you need is set up the **TZ** environment variable with the right value:

```
export TZ="Brazil/East"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose from one of the time zones [in this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

If by "BRT" you mean Brasilia Time, then you should use `"America/Sao_Paulo"`.

Comment: thanks, I already have noticed that but I would like to know if there is a different/better way of selecting this in the context of the plone.app.event add on for the Plone CMS.